# Ruby-tk installation in `rbenv` in Linux Mint 17 'Qiana'

Tags: ruby, tcl, tk-toolkit

I installed Ruby 2.3.0 via `rbenv` and now I need to install tk plugin there. I downloaded and installed `ActiveTcl` and also ran

```
$ sudo apt-get install libtcltk-ruby
```

but when I try to test it in `irb` running

```
require 'tk'
```

it returns me that Ruby cannot find such file. What have I done wrong and how to install ruby-tk bindings properly?

**EDIT**: I installed Ruby according to  the [official Ubuntu guide](https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/16.04)

Tcl and Tk are also installed

Comment: You should have installed Tcl and Tk using `apt-get` as well. Something like `sudo apt-get install tk8.5 tcl8.5`…

Comment: @DonalFellows they are already installed

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you've already installed tk via: `sudo apt-get install tk`
2. Make sure your ruby version has been installed with tk: https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/77
3. Try `require`ing tk directly via `require '<ruby_path>/ext/tk/lib/tk'`

If step 3 gives an error, post it here and hopefully we can be of more help.

Comment: did as you said, so
1. tk and tcl are already installed
3. checked it via `require '/home/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/ext/tk/lib/tk'`, didn't help, error is the following: `LoadError: cannot load such file -- /home/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/ext/tk/lib/tk
 from /home/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in 'require'
 from /home/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in 'require'
 from (irb):1
 from /home/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/irb:11:in '<main>'`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the installation of Ruby/Tk  is painful.
You have to check your tck/tk library location , and pass options to `gem install` command. Below is my example.Sometimes you have to reinstall Ruby/Tk when you want to use extra tk libraries (not always). If you don't hate GNOME, Ruby/Gtk is also a good choice.
Good luck.

```
gem install tk -- --with-tcltkversion=8.6 \
--with-tcl-lib=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu \
--with-tk-lib=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu \
--with-tcl-include=/usr/include/tcl8.6 \
--with-tk-include=/usr/include/tcl8.6 \
--enable-pthread
```